logistic regressions using statsmodel and pyspark result in different estimations
I have tested statsmodel and various pyspark ml packages for logistic regression with weightCol feature and found the model estimations vary.
For my particular tests:

statsmodel and pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression have the same estimations
pyspark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegression has different estimation with huge coefficient estimation for some features
by removing weightCol, the results are the same for 1 and 2

Any insight on why pyspark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegression performs differently?
The pyspark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegression is preferred pyspark package as I need the offsetCol feature.
Is there any way that can help bring the model fitting results the same as the other two? Or is there any way to have the offsetCol feature available for pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression?
I also tried the regParam=0.1 for pyspark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegression and the coefficient estimation tend to be much smaller than statsmodel results.
Any advice on the regParam setting?
Many thanks!
Update:
by normalizing weights, the issue is gone. Not sure why the convergence issue only happens to pyspark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegression.
